# Binding the progress bar in Visual Studio to async process android Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, android-progressbar

I have been trying to bind the download process of a YoutubeDownloader to a progress bar in Xamarin. However I have failed miserably while trying to do thus far. The download is proceeding succesfully. I tried both the android notification download progress bar and the progressbar provided by visual studio (xamarin). I use the 'YoutubeExplode' library for the download process. I would like to know how to get each one working, however one solution would suffice.

```
                var id = YoutubeClient.ParseVideoId(ytlink);
                var video = await client.GetVideoAsync(id);

                var title = video.Title;
                var StreamInfoSet = await client.GetVideoMediaStreamInfosAsync(id);
                var StreamInfo = StreamInfoSet.Audio.WithHighestBitrate();

                await client.DownloadMediaStreamAsync(StreamInfo, System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, title + ".mp3"));
```

EDIT (Still don't get the progressbar to work:

```
var handler = new Progress<double>(p => Progress = p);
                await client.DownloadMediaStreamAsync(StreamInfo, System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, title + ".mp3"),handler);
```

Comment: There is a full example in the repo (line 171) : https://github.com/Tyrrrz/YoutubeExplode/blob/c837d17d24ed77fa181eb47a046bb0da95c2b9fb/DemoWpf/ViewModels/MainViewModel.cs#L171

Comment: @SushiHangover I edited the code (see post). But no progressbar shows up. Maybe I need to bind the progress to the progressbar somehow? Care to explain?

Comment: Yes, you need to bind it but also make sure setting `Progress` actually invokes `INotifyPropertyChanged` event.
Here's the binding in the repo (line 65): https://github.com/Tyrrrz/YoutubeExplode/blob/c837d17d24ed77fa181eb47a046bb0da95c2b9fb/DemoWpf/Views/MainWindow.xaml#L65